# jQuery slide up not working as expected

Tags: jquery, slide

I am trying to create a simple slide up jquery function so that when a visitor hovers over a div, an add-to-cart option slides up.  This is what I have so far

```
$(".archive").hover(function () {
  $(".addtocart").slideToggle("fast");
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/E9Bh6/

My problems are...

- All of the divs are affected instead of individually, so if I hover over one div, the add-to-cart message slides up on all of them
- The div is sliding down, I want it to slide up

Where am I going wrong?

Comment: If the cart is `display:none` how is anyone supposed to see it? Also, your fiddle doesn't include jQuery and the code doesn't match what you posted above.

Comment: you looking for something like this? http://jsfiddle.net/E9Bh6/3/ also your code was completely wrong.

Comment: Or is that what you're after? http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/E9Bh6/4/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're activating all the divs with the class '.addtocart'.

You need to use $(this) to only activate the one you are hovering over.

```
$(".archive").hover(function () {
  $(this).find('.addtocart').slideToggle("fast");
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Change it into this:

```
$(".archive").hover(function () {
  $(this).children(".addtocart").slideToggle("fast");
});
```

I edited your fiddle into [this](http://jsfiddle.net/E9Bh6/2/).. Hope it helps..